# How can I stop specs of light coming through my object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I am currently creating a pumpkin to sing (don't ask) I have got it singing but I have realized that I have specs of lighting coming on the outside of my pumpkin. I really need to get rid of all these light specs on the outsides as it is not very good. I have tried moving the light around etc. but have not solving the issue.
[image: My pumpkin]

Comment: What you are calling specs of light is really just noise.  It looks to me like you just need to knock up the samples under *properties editor* > *render panel* > *sampling* > *render spinner*.  See the question David linked for more explination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn of caustics in the render settings.

here is a superb video that tells how to fix all types of problems like that.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbj4d5XL0NA

watch min. 32 for your specific problem.

Comment: glad i could help.